# Why End error in For Loop Error with Robot Framework

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

Why I am getting for loop must have closing END though I have already added it
The first function is working as expected but the second one is throwing error kindly suggest whats wrong here

```
*** Settings ***
Library          SeleniumLibrary                          # importing selenium library



*** Variables ***
@{ROBOTS}=    Bender    Johnny5    Terminator    Robocop

***Test Cases***
somefunc1
    FOR                 ${i}         IN RANGE         999999
    Exit For Loop If    ${i} == 9
    Log                 ${i}
    Log To Console      ${i}         stream=STDOUT    no_newline=False
    END
    Log                 Exited

Create List and Loop

    FOR    ${robot}    IN    @{ROBOTS}
    Log    ${robot}
    End
```

Output I am getting is

```
somefunc1                                                             0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
somefunc1                                                             | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Create List and Loop                                                  | FAIL |
FOR loop must have closing END.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did not write the last end in caps. Shouldn't it be END ?

Comment: OMG correct so embarrassed now thanks was hitting my head since last 15 min

Comment: Happens to everyone. Sometimes the fastest way is to get a fresh perspective as you did !